# how to make a htaccess rule from id to name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a list of unique data:

Suppose I have the following data:

```
id    name
1     Jhon
2     Peter 
3     Mark
4     Scotty
5     Marry
```

I make a `.htaccess` rule for `id`:

```
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)/ site/brandlisting?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*) site/brandlisting?id=$1 [L]
```

my URL is:

```
http://localhost/mate/admin/site/brandlisting/3
```

this works for id.

Now I need a `.htaccess` rule for name, so I make a rule for it:

```
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)/ site/brandlisting?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*) site/brandlisting?name=$1 [L]

http://localhost/mate/admin/site/brandlisting/Mark
```

When I used the above URL I was faced with following error in the console:

> "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request -
>   http://localhost/mate/admin/site/brandlisting/Mark"

and in browser it shows:

> Error 400 Your request is invalid.

**My current .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/mate/admin$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/mate/admin$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wordpress/
RewriteRule (.*) /wordpress/$1 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

#RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)/ site/brandlisting?id=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*) site/brandlisting?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)/ site/brandlisting?name=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*) site/brandlisting?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Go check the server’s error log.

Comment: @CBroe everything is fine in server's error log

Comment: What do you mean, “fine”? The server responded with an error, so that should be in the logs.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2017:15:49:09 +0530] "GET /mate/admin/images/yelp.JPG HTTP/1.1" 304 182 "http://localhost/mate/admin/site/brandlisting/Coaster%20Furniture" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"

Comment: above logged in log  file

Comment: That is from the access log, not the error log. Plus, it is a different URL than the one you mentioned above, and it also does not have a 400 status code.

Comment: [Fri Jan 20 15:44:44.520109 2017] [core:error] [pid 13928] [client 127.0.0.1:50777] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Might be due to the order of your rules. You should always place the more specific ones first, and the less specific ones after.

Comment: can you try like this RewriteRule brandlisting/[A-Za-z+]/ site/brand....

Comment: @NaveedRamzan i tried this but not works

Comment: but... the structure for your "id" route (`http://localhost/mate/admin/site/brandlisting/3`) and your "name" route (`http://localhost/mate/admin/site/brandlisting/Mark`) is exactly the same... do you want to differentiate them by one being numeric and the other containing characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` rules rely on order. If you anticipate using a lot of routes, keep your htaccess rules simple and put your routes into PHP instead, using one of the several already written routing frameworks.

Here's an explanation as to why your `.htaccess` file isn't working, line-by-line:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

This turned the RewriteEngine on. No problems so far.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/mate/admin$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/mate/admin$    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wordpress/
```

Only match `RewriteRule` is it's WordPress. This seems to be working, so let's ignore this block of rules.

```
RewriteRule (.*) /wordpress/$1 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Only match below if the requested filename is not a file or a directory.

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Rewrite any path `PATH` to index.php/`PATH`. Stop processing if it matched (note the `L` as **last**). That means nothing below will be activated.

```
#RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)/ site/brandlisting?id=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*) site/brandlisting?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)/ site/brandlisting?name=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*) site/brandlisting?name=$1 [L]
```

Assuming that it doesn't match `.*` (aka, never), check path for other patterns. Note also that the two lines you have commented, and the two lines you don't, both match the same pattern. If one worked, the other would not.

-- *Pro Tip*: Regex has a shorthand for including a rule with a trailing slash and without one: `/?` is equivalent to, either with one slash, or with no slashes. Another way to write this is `/{0,1}`.

## How to Fix

`.htaccess` redirect rules are a pain. My rule of thumb is to make them as easy as possible to write, which makes them easy to read and to maintain. How to do this? Push the redirect logic to your PHP program, rather than forcing Apache to rely on it.

## Solution 1

The `htaccess`-only approach here would be to ensure you understand what [Apache rewrite flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) are telling your server to do, and adjust accordingly. You can do this here one of two ways:

1. Make your more specific rules show up first. i.e., move `/site/brandlisting?name=$1` rules to before `.*` rules.
2. Add a separate rewrite conditions for any followup processing. As per the Apache2 documentation linked above:

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

The key point here is that it is **within each rule set**. Building a new rule set will continue processing.

Example that should work (not tested):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/mate/admin$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/mate/admin$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wordpress/
RewriteRule (.*) /wordpress/$1 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

#New Rule Set
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Note that /? is the same as writing two separate rules,
# one with a slash at the end, and one without.
RewriteRule brandlisting/(.*)/? site/brandlisting?name=$1 [L]
```

There are some great pre-built routers out there, like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) and [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/). If you don't want to use them, you can still use your own internal logic that parses various pieces. From my experience, the more that I can pull out of my `.htaccess` file, the happier you'll be. It winds up being far easier to debug issues, and it's easier to iterate changes without introducing unintended consequences.

## Solution 2

You can use PHP routers in conjunction with the `.htaccess` file I provided above, like so:

```
// Slim example
$app = new Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/brandlisting/:key', function ($key) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
        $id = $key;
        // call/run $id logic
    } else {
        $name = $key;
        // call/run $name logic
    }
});
// ...
$app->run();
```

If you do this, you can remove any of your `brandlisting` logic from `.htaccess` and instead put it into your `index.php`.

## Conclusion

If you can help it, experience tells me that it's better to not write your app logic into `.htaccess` rules. Instead, make your `.htaccess` rules simple and use a routing library. If you want to use `.htaccess`, make sure you understand the [Apache rewrite flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) you're using, and that Apache reads everything from top to bottom. For example, if the `[L]` flag is used, Apache stops reading all other rules ***in the rule set***. That means, you have to create a new rule set with additional rules that need to be processed, or put your more specific rules first. Keep in mind that, if those rules have an `[L]` flag, they will also stop execution of any subsequent rules.

Answer (score 2):

I am starting with your current `.htaccess` you have crunch all the available rule which meets your needs in one single `.htaccess` for example rule for wordpress it should be in directory where your wordpress is installed.

Your rule as per your requirement should be like this if you are trying in root directory,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /mate/admin/

RewriteRule site/brandlisting/([\d]+)/?$ site/brandlisting.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule site/brandlisting/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ site/brandlisting.php?name=$1 [L]
```

And for wordpress you directory you can create seperate .htaccess where you can put your rule index.php.

Comment: I removed wordress rule, but still an error. 

Error 400
Your request is invalid.

Comment: Please try the edit now, I think I was missing .php to brandlisting although this rule is working for me.

Comment: not success. is there any other .htaccess calls? because in subfolder there is another .htaccess files and in each subfolder's .htaccess file has "deny from all" this sentence only. i comment this line from all subfolders, but nothing happens.

Comment: This might be a problem because you clearly have very large url and I don't know what is written in .htaccess of other folders but above rule is working for me as described try to change the rule and `.htaccess` according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use redirect here.

Assuming you have the following folders:

```
<server root>/mate/admin
```

place in .htaccess in mate/admin

```
RewriteBase /mate/admin/
RewriteRule "site/brandlisting/([^\\]+)/" "site/brandlisting?id=$1" [R,L]
RewriteRule "site/brandlisting/([^\\]+)" "site/brandlisting?id=$1" [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into an issue where a Directory or other directive is causing your rewrite rules to repeatedly fire and cause infinite redirects.

See the documentation for [RewriteRule Flags: L](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l).

Specifically, the following quoted text is relevant:

> If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in
>    sections, it is important to have some understanding of
>   how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that once
>   the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to
>   the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that
>   as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or 
>   section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run
>   again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the
>   rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the
>   request process to start over.
>
> It is therefore important, if you are using RewriteRule directives in
>   one of these contexts, that you take explicit steps to avoid rules
>   looping, and not count solely on the [L] flag to terminate execution
>   of a series of rules, as shown below.

You may need to add a rewrite condition or take other steps to prevent looping.